# Cucumber 7 regex on step definition

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I am new to cucumber and regex .
I am currently using cucumber core 7.2.0 for a project.

For some reason I cannot seem to get regular expressions to work in the step definition.

For example I have the following

```
Scenario: User tries to login

When I enter valid credentials for test@test.com
```

Then on step definition class

```
@When("I enter (.*) credentials for {word}")
 public void iEnterMyCredentialsAsUser(String email) {
      System.out.println(email);

}
```

While the feature finds the step definition found just fine, when executing I get the following

io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The step 'I enter valid credentials for testa30' is undefined.
You can implement this step using the snippet(s) below:

```
   @When("I enter valid credentials for testa30")
   public void i_enter_valid_credentials_for_testa30() {
   // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
   throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
 }
```

Basically I want to only care about the email as a parameter and not care about "valid"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To let Cucumber know you are using regular expressions, start your definition with `^` and end with `$`. See details [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/blob/main/java/heuristics.adoc).

More over do not mix up regular expressions and cucumber expressions. Syntax like `{word}` is not supported when you use regular expression approach.

Comment: Thank you, got it to work with your suggestion , will make sure not to combine both regex and cucumber expressions